# Remove duplicate comparisons in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I have a polygon layer named `scale_polygons_v4`. I want to get ids of overlapping polygons. I have tried the code below:

```
select distinct s1.id,s2.id from scale_polygons_v4 s1 
inner join scale_polygons_v4 s2
on s1.id!=s2.id and s1.kind=s2.kind and st_overlaps(s1.geom,s2.geom)
```

The results are correct, but with duplicate comparisons it returns for example:

```
10029161,10011031
10011031,10029161
```

There are multiple such cases I only want to get one comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `least()` and `greatest()` for this:

```
select distinct least(s1.id, s2.id), greatest(s1.id, s2.id) 
from scale_polygons_v4 s1 
  join scale_polygons_v4 s2
    on s1.id <> s2.id 
   and s1.kind = s2.kind 
   and st_overlaps(s1.geom,s2.geom);
```

Another option is to do this in the join condition:

```
select distinct s1.id, s2.id 
from scale_polygons_v4 s1 
  join scale_polygons_v4 s2
    on s1.id > s2.id 
   and s1.kind = s2.kind 
   and st_overlaps(s1.geom,s2.geom);
```